# Flyback Transformer Active Snubber Design

Tags: transformer, flyback, snubber

I'm using a flyback transformer along with the LT3750 controller by Linear to charge a capacitor. I'm wanting to increase efficiency and improve the circuit. I began with looking into an RC snubber to relieve some of the voltage stress on the mosfet. In reading about the trade-offs of using snubbers I ran into what's called an active snubber.

[image: active snubber circuit]
<sub>(source: [sanantoniowebagent.com](http://sanantoniowebagent.com/pyro/active_snubber_design.jpg))</sub>

From what I understand an active snubber diverts the leakage inductance energy back into the Vin line. The circuit requires a second mosfet, an inductor and a diode. I'm trying to research this solution but cannot find any additional information. I would think repurposing that lost energy and putting it back into the Vin line would be much more efficient versus dissipating through a resistor.

Any thoughts on active snubbers for efficiency?
Any insight on how to design such a circuit?

Comment: Google "active clamp flyback" and you'll find a lot more information.

Comment: @JohnD good info. Just searched it up, and it seems very interesting.

Comment: @JohnD thanks! I looked over a lot of that material. It seems most active clamp techniques use an IC with two gate outputs. One for the main switch and one for the auxiliary - due to the needed delay between the switches, when one is off the other is on. My IC however only has 1 gate output. What to do?

Comment: I'm not sure you can make a robust active clamp flyback without a controller with a specific output for the active clamp or lots of extra external circuitry.